# How can I split a buffered audio signal into multiple frequency bands for visualisation in C?

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, c, visualization

Currently, I am trying to split a buffered audio signal (buffer size = 1024 samples) into several bands in order to output a bunch of numeric values of their levels (calculated as RMS values). So far, I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

// Random numbers generated with the command
// python -c 'import random; ran = random.Random(); print([ran.randint(0, 65536) for _ in range(1024)])'
// for testing purposes
// Ommited from StackExchange post for length reasons
short buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 57054, 11874, ..., 22716, 57055 };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long buffer_sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
        buffer_sum += buffer[i]*buffer[i];
    }

    double rms = sqrt(buffer_sum/BUFFER_SIZE);
    double Pvalue = rms * 0.45255;
    double dB = 20 * log10(Pvalue);

    printf("%lf\n", dB);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this code can only output the average gain of the entire frequency spectrum. Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is an effect like you can see [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCD2tB1qILc), but with raw numbers being output (printed to stdout as a simple comma-separated list) instead of a graphical visualization. What would be a good way to go about this? To be clear, the primary goal is to be a basic visualizer, so the filter doesn't need to be very accurate. Phase issues and such aren't very important here. It should, however, be fast to calculate in real time.

PS: Please note that I am very new to both DSP and the C programming language, as well as not being particularly great at math.

Comment: For visualization, C is far from the ideal language of choice. Python's [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html) makes it as easy as `plt.plot(x)`. Same with printing or really anything unless it can't be vectorized, but sure, just printing isn't hard in C. This more belongs on StackOverflow, just reformulate "signal" as "1D array".

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The reason why I chose C is that A: I read the audio in real time using ALSA, and B: it has to run as a real time process (rather than pre-generating the data), so it has to run fairly fast. As for SO, I'll re-ask this question there.

Comment: I can do it in python in realtime using Pyaudio(portaudio) to play and matplotlib to visualizer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw6jbAbvsvo

Comment: @ederwander Fair enough, I'll have a look at Matplotlib then. I just hope this won't make my CPU explode.

Comment: @SkyyySi Unless you're running it on a microchip or similar, it won't make a difference. "Python slow" is mostly a myth. You could also do both with [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: @ederwander I know that Python's speed difference compared to native code typically doesn't matter at all (who really cares if something likes this uses 0.05% or 0.5% CPU?). My concern came from some programs with spectrum analyzers I used in the past having consumed quite a bit of CPU, and those were all native applications to my knowledge. Then again, your video was recorded >9 years ago, so I doubt it'll be an issue on a modern Ryzen 7.

Comment: @SkyyySi 9 years ago this notebook was already considered an old model lol ... 
i did really expensive and complex stuff in python at the time, some stuff used up to 50% cpu 9 years ago lol take a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YT-zAX3S850 .. this use FFT code from Numpy python Library .... I have coded it in Pure C too and yes in C is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to build real time audio spectrum analyzer.

There are two main methods that are typically used

1. Build a logarithmically spaced bandpass filter bank with IIR filters
2. Use a short term Fourier Transform and integrate each frame over the target frequency bands (typically octaves or third octaves).

The best choice depends on the number of bands and also what method you  are more comfortable with. Generally, for higher number of bands method 2 is more efficient.

> but with raw numbers being output (printed to stdout as a simple comma-separated list)

Sorry, that doesn't make a lot of sense. With a frame size of 1024 and a sample rate of 44.1kHz you will be getting roughly 44 frames per second. For a third octave analyzer you will get 30 numbers per frame, you would be putting out over 1300 numbers per second. No one can read that.

> PS: Please note that I am very new to both DSP and the C programming language, as well as not being particularly great at math.

DSP is pretty math heavy. I would rate this project "easy" to "moderate" in complexity but it's not exactly a "beginner" project especially if you have to come up in three different skills at the same time.

Comment: The raw numbers are because I need to pass them that way into another app. Obviously, I'm not trying to read that from a terminal.